# laravel relacion de 2 tablas con una tabla pivot

Tags: laravel

hola buenas noches tengo una dificultad estoy queriendo obtener un dato de una tabla pivot pero no lo logro, estas son las tablas relacionadas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el controlador ShoppingCartsController.php

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\ShoppingCart;

use App\InShoppingCart;

class ShoppingCartsController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
       $shopping_cart_id = \Session::get('shopping_cart_id');

        $shopping_cart = ShoppingCart::findOrCreateSessionID($shopping_cart_id);

        $products = $shopping_cart->InShoppingCart()->get();

        $total = $shopping_cart->total();

        return view('shopping_carts.index', ['products'=>$products, 'shopping_cart' => $shopping_cart, 'total' => $total]);

    }
}
```

Y este es el modelo:

```html
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ShoppingCart extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = ['status'];

  public function inShoppingCarts(){
   return $this->hasMany('App\InShoppingCart');
  }

  public function products(){
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'in_shopping_carts');
  }

  public function productsSize(){
   return $this->products()->count();
  }

  public function total(){
   return $this->products()->sum('pricing');
  }

     public static function findOrCreateSessionID($shopping_cart_id){
     if($shopping_cart_id)
      return ShoppingCart::findBySession($shopping_cart_id);
     else
      return ShoppingCart::createWithoutSession();
    }

 public static function findBySession($shopping_cart_id){
  return ShoppingCart::find($shopping_cart_id);
 }


 public static function createWithoutSession(){

  return ShoppingCart::Create([
   'status' => 'incompleted'
  ]);
 }
}
```

y aqui el controlador InShoppingCartsController.php:`

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\ShoppingCart;

use App\InShoppingCart;

class InShoppingCartsController extends Controller
{
    
    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('shoppingcart');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
         $shopping_cart = $request->shopping_cart;

         $response = InShoppingCart::create([
            'shopping_cart_id' => $shopping_cart->id,
            'product_id' => $request->product_id
         ]);
         if(false){
            return redirect('/carrito');
         }else{
            return back();
         }
    }

    

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

`

Tengo aquí el modelo de InShoppingCarts:

```html
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class InShoppingCart extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
     'product_id', 'shopping_cart_id'
    ];
}
```

en mi vista obtengo:

```
           @foreach($products as $product)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $product -> id }}</td>
```

```
                </tr>
            @endforeach
```

Lo que necesito es poder borrar o eliminar un producto del listado.Alguna sugerencia de como hacerlo, va a ser muy valiosa cualquier pista?

Por favor si se necesita más información indicarme. Mil gracias de antemano

Saludos y gracias

#

Veo que si yo pudiera iterar la tabla in_shopping_carts podría borrar un elemento por su id y lo puedo hacer cambiando la linea en **ShoppingCartsController**:

```
$products = $shopping_cart->products()->get;
```

por:

```
$products = $shopping_cart->InShoppingCart()->get();
```

en ese caso me entrega:

id

product_id

shopping_cart_id

mediante id podría borrar un producto que me aparece en la lista, pero lo que no logro conseguir es que me de el nombre del producto, solo me da el id del producto con **product_id**
tal vez pudiendo imprimir el nombre del producto ya tendría solucionado mi problema, por ahi alguna sugerencia de como hacerlo?

Aquí paso una imagen de lo obtenido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

El error está en el momento al momento de obtener los productos

Tenes que reemplazar esta linea :

```
$products = $shopping_cart->InShoppingCart()->get();
```

Por esta :

```
$products = $shopping_cart->products;
```

De esta manera laravel accede a la tabla pivot y te devuelve una `Collection` de objetos `Product`

Te dejo un link de la docu de laravel donde explica esa parte! 
[Laravel : Many To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Para poder un elemento de la tabla pivot en tu caso `in_shopping_carts`, podes usar funcion `detach`.

El codigo quedaria de la siguiente manera :

```
$shopping_cart->products()->detach($productId);
```

Donde `$shopping_cart` es el objeto de tu carrito de compra, y `$productId` es el producto que deseas eliminar de tu tabla pivot.

Te dejo una referencia a la documentación de laravel [Attach and detach elements from pivot table](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)

Saludos

Comment: hola, si ya lo solucioné, pero ahora me queda poder borrar un elemento del listado, alguna idea de como hacerlo? estoy añadiendo en el post las tablas de las migraciones. Gracias

Comment: hola Sergio gracias por tu respuesta, abajo en la parte final de mi pregunta he añadido exactamente lo que me falta. Agradeceré un montón tu comentario. Gracias

Comment: Edito la respuesta, y te constesto aca mismo.

Comment: Hola Sergio, pude resolver mi problema añadiendo una columna a la tabla in_shopping_carts  product_title y al formulario que llena esa tabla le agregue un campo hidden con el nombre de producto, creo que ahi va solucionado mi tema. Gracias